# Build user interface based on text values

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-interface, types, polymorphism

I need to add UI objects to a page based on the string results of a query. "textbox,textbox,checkbox,textbox", for example, would display 3 textbox items and a checkbox item on the screen. I also need to read the values that each holds when the user clicks a button.

I'm having a difficult time determining how to hold different types of objects within a collection so I can read all of the values back in the correct order, regardless of the type. I will need some sort of polymorphism for adding and reading the values. Any ideas to push me in the right direction?

Comment: Check my answer below. Also, Javascript and JSON adapt well to polymorphing as nothing is hard-typed like in C#, it is all key/value pairing strings, and it is definitely where you should handle UI issues rather than on the server. Just make sure your server-side code takes your C# objects, parse it to a JSON string, send it to the browser... then it can be parsed back to a javascript object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 const string TEXTBOX = "textbox";
    const string CHECKBOX = "checkbox";

    //assuming your result set is placed in a data table or dictionary we can enumerate through //the result set and based on the text comparison add a check box or textbox.  

    Panel panel = new Panel();

    DataTable dataTable = getResultSet();
    foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
    {
        string comparison = row["<columnNameContaining yuur "TextBox" or "CheckBox text>"].value;
        switch(comparison)
        {
            case TEXTBOX:
                textBox = new TextBox();
                panel.Controls.Add(textBox);
                break;
            case CHECKBOX;
                CheckBox checkBox = new checkBox();
                panel.Controls.Add(checkBox);
                break;
        }
     }
```

Hope this helps. Also if you want to specify names for your checkboxes and textboxes you may also want to store those in your data store so you can at least assign a unique ID that can later be used when you want to read values back in from the UI To do so you would use the FindControl() method and pass in the unique ID name. It would look something like this.

```
Textbox textBox = (TextBox)panel.FindControl("<unique ID");
if(textBox != null)
{
    string value = textBox.Text;
}
```

I used a similar method to populate and retrieve values from a detailsView that doens't use the generic data sources to populate and retrieve values using my business logic layer.

Comment: I ended up going with something similar to this. Since I had several other properties associated with the UI element, I still wanted to store them in a class and create a list. I still think that there's a better way to handle it, but this certainly got me across the finish line. Thanks!

Comment: I think you may be able to use a List of WebControls as both TextBox and CheckBox inherit from the WebControl class. You can use this list to populate the form but you would have to cast them to either CheckBox or TextBox when you want to read values back from the controls. If you use this method you may want to use Linq otherwise your stuck using an ADO object like a DataTable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Start with an empty form in your HTML page:

```
<form>
    <div id="formElementsContainer">

    </div>
</form>
```

Structure the string returned to the client as JSON data. Something like this might work for a single item

```
{
    "ui-model": "textbox",
    "value": {"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", /* etc */ }
}
```

-- or something like this for a collection --

```
{
    "uimodel": "checkbox",
    "value": { "myCollection": [
        {"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", /* etc */ },
        {"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", /* etc */ },
        {"prop1": "value1", "prop2": "value2", /* etc */ }
    ]}
}
```

Use jQuery/Javascript to parse the JSON into javascript objects:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(/* your JSON data here */)
```

Say Prop1 is the item name, and prop2 is the value going in the textbox. Use the object's data to build your form elements, and add them to the form elements container:

```
var ui = data.uimodel;  // textbox
var obj = data.value;

var textbox = '<input type="' + ui + '" id="' + obj.prop1 +'">' + obj.prop2 + '</input>';
$('#formElementsContainer').append(textbox);
```

this is a very simple example, and of course double check the code, but it will get you started. then when you post the form back to the server, the input item values will get sent back for you to use C# server-side.

Comment: One thing to note... if you want to send things back on a larger scale, you could simply wrap the object item examples above within a larger JSON collection, and write logic to enumerate through the collection programaticaly.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to associate the object values with a dictionary. Its values will be updated by the relative event handlers you will create for each object.